# PHP Strip_Tags calling only first term in array

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

So I'm stuck on a problem. I'm not familiar with {{{ }}} in a php document. I'm editing a theme wordpress file, that works with WP Job Manager and I can't seem to call a tag from an array that has worked in other php documents in the theme. I'm using the code below to call the array but it won't call anything but the first term in the array.

---

```
<?php 
$jobTypes = strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'job_listing_category', ' ',', '));
$daySpa = 'Day Spa';

if (strpos($jobTypes, $daySpa) !== false) {
echo "{{{data.location.address}}}"; 
};
?>"
```

---

Below is a portion of the php that I've incorporated the line to call the array to hide {{{data.location.address}}} unless the term is equal to "Day Spa" in the array, but all of them are pulling Day Spa, even when the profile connected is not assigned that term.

The image below is what the result is. I'm trying to remove the address if the tag from the array does not equal "Day Spa"
[image: Template Listing Cards]

---

```
<div class="job_listing-entry-meta">
                    <# if ( data.status.featured && 'badge' === data.styles.featuredStyle ) { #>
                        <div class="listing-featured-badge">{{data.i18n.featured}}</div>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.title ) { #>
                        <h3 class="job_listing-title">{{{data.title}}}</h3>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.address && data.location ) { #>
                        <div class="job_listing-location">
                        <?php 
                        $jobTypes = strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'job_listing_category', ' ',', '));
                        $daySpa = 'Day Spa';

                        if (strpos($jobTypes, $daySpa) !== false) {
                            echo "{{{data.location.address}}}"; 
                        };

                        ?>
                        </div>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.telephone && data.telephone ) { #>
                        <div class="job_listing-phone">{{data.telephone}}</div>
                    <# } #>

                    <?php
                        /**
                         * Insert content after other meta information.
                         *
                         * @since unknown
                         */
                        do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_meta' );
                    ?>
                </div><div class="job_listing-entry-meta">
                    <# if ( data.status.featured && 'badge' === data.styles.featuredStyle ) { #>
                        <div class="listing-featured-badge">{{data.i18n.featured}}</div>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.title ) { #>
                        <h3 class="job_listing-title">{{{data.title}}}</h3>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.address && data.location ) { #>
                        <div class="job_listing-location">
                        <?php 
                        $jobTypes = strip_tags(get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'job_listing_category', ' ',', '));
                        $daySpa = 'Day Spa';

                        if (strpos($jobTypes, $daySpa) !== false) {
                            echo "{{{data.location.address}}}"; 
                        };

                        ?>
                        </div>
                    <# } #>

                    <# if ( data.cardDisplay.telephone && data.telephone ) { #>
                        <div class="job_listing-phone">{{data.telephone}}</div>
                    <# } #>

                    <?php
                        /**
                         * Insert content after other meta information.
                         *
                         * @since unknown
                         */
                        do_action( 'listify_content_job_listing_meta' );
                    ?>
                </div>
```